# Why can I access a public website from within a virtual machine but not outside of it?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, networking, connection, microsoft-edge

Getting a strange problem right now. Specifically, I cannot access **id.unity.com** from any browser on one of my PCs at home (I've tried Edge, Chrome and Firefox). It comes back with:

```
This page isn’t working right now
id.unity.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

(Edge; Chrome)

```
Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to id.unity.com.
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
```

(Firefox)

However, I can access the same website quite happily using Firefox within a Linux virtual machine hosted on the same PC.

I can also access the site from two other Windows PCs at home (and also a Mac), on multiple browsers.

I can ping **id.unity.com** with no obvious issues from the problem PC.

I've tried flushing caches and calling **ipconfig /flushdns**. No joy. I tried disabling my firewall.

I don't really have the expertise in this area to diagnose the problem further.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I eventually discovered that a piece of "threat protection software" I don't ever remember signing up for was running as a process and causing various website connections to fail (sometimes silently, by refusing to populate a subset of the page). In my specific case it was NordVPN's Threat Protection. Ugh. When I was eventually able to kill it and stop it reviving itself, the issue went away.